# How to fix problem with jQuery .post() function in internet explorer?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have a javascript and jquery code like:

```
$("#refreshimg").live('click',function(){

$.post('php/newsession.php');
$("#captchaimage").load('php/image_req.php');
return false;

});
```

It is working everywhere except internet explorer (7,8,9). The image is perfectly reloaded in opera, firefox, chrome but not in explorer.

And my html looks like:

```
<div id="captchaimage"><img src="captcha/image.php?<?php echo time(); ?>" alt="Captcha image" width="132" height="26" align="left" /></div>
```

Could be there a problem with **.live()** or **.post()** or **.load()** jQuery function in explorer?

Then I have in my code in the main file:

```
$("#back_btn").click(function() {

                                         $.post('php/newsession.php');
                                         $("#captchaimage").load('php/image_req.php');

                                            return false;  

                        });
```

And again, this works everywhere except the internet explorer. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

You are reloading image but you are not waiting for request to be done. So what you can do is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#refreshimg").live('click',function(){

$.ajax({url: 'php/newsession.php', type: 'post', success: function() { $("#captchaimage").load('php/image_req.php?custom_param='+(new Date()).valueOf()); } });

return false;

  });
});
```

and also add no-cache to your php file

```
 <?
  Header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
  Header('Pragma: no-cache');
  ?>
```

make sure that code above is at the first line, because headers needs to be set first.

and this will work.

Comment: Hi, thanks however it is still the same in internet explorer. I have updated the info about my javascript, because I have other function for my back button, which should reload the captcha image. However, in firefox, chrome, opera it works but in explorer not. Any advice?

Comment: It bothers me because it happens just in explorer. Other browsers are fine.

Comment: maybe there is problem with the caching, you can also set no cache in php, but I will update this post so you can be sure